# Calculate percentage for a given date range in sql procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Table Structure:

```
Col1  col2  col3 col4
1     ABC   q    03-11-2018   
2     ABC   q    03-11-2018
3     ABC   q    03-11-2018
4     PBC   q    03-11-2018
5     ABC   q    04-11-2018
6     ABC   q    04-11-2018
7     ABC   q    05-11-2018
```

Expected O/P:
calculate percentage by the following formula
count(col2) where col=ABC & total rows count

suppose user give date between 03-11-2018 to 05-11-2018 then output should be

```
col1  col2   col3
3     3      100%
2     2      100%
1     1      100%
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the time to read how to ask a good question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can try like following.

```
 DECLARE @StartDate DATE='03-11-2018' 
 DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '05-11-2018'; 

;WITH cte AS
      (SELECT Count(*) col1, 
                col4 
         FROM   temp_table 
         WHERE  col2 = 'ABC' 
         GROUP  BY col4) 
SELECT col1, 
       col2, 
       Str(col1 * 100.0/col2, 12, 2) + '%' AS Col3 
FROM   cte c 
       CROSS apply (SELECT Count(*) col2 
                    FROM   temp_table T 
                    WHERE  C.col4 = T.col4)TOT 
WHERE  C.col4 BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/CLHWMS14050)

Note: Replace `TEMP_TABLE`  with your actual table name.